# J2EE DAO gives 404 error

Tags: jakarta-ee, dao

I tried to make my own Java J2EE DAO. It keeps giving me a 404 error. I also tried to send a GET request, again a 404 error. I have all the correct imports, web.xml, pom.xml, etc. I quadruple checked those.

I'm trying to get only the "ingredientnaam" variable from my DAO at the url /restservices/ingredients. Using Eclipse, there are 0 errors.

Does anybody know of a functional DAO that I could edit to suit my DAO? Or does anybody see any mistakes in my code? Much appreciated.

IngredientResource.java

```
@Path("/ingredients")
public class IngredientResource {

    @GET
    @Produces("application/json")
    public String getIngredients() {
        IngredientService service = ServiceProvider.getIngredientService();
        JsonArray ingredientArray = buildJsonCountryArray(service.getAllIngredients());
        System.out.println(service.getAllIngredients());
        return ingredientArray.toString();
    }


    private JsonArray buildJsonCountryArray(List<Ingredient> ingredients) {
        JsonArrayBuilder jsonArrayBuilder = Json.createArrayBuilder();

        for (Ingredient c : ingredients) {
            JsonObjectBuilder job = Json.createObjectBuilder();

            job.add("ingredientnaam", c.getIngredientnaam());

            jsonArrayBuilder.add(job);
        }

        return jsonArrayBuilder.build();
    }
}
```

IngredientDAO.java

```
public class IngredientDAO extends BaseDAO {
    private IngredientDAO ingredientDAO = new IngredientDAO();

    private List<Ingredient> selectIngredients(String query) {
        List<Ingredient> results = new ArrayList<Ingredient>();

        try (Connection con = super.getConnection()) {
            Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
            ResultSet dbResultSet = stmt.executeQuery(query);

            while (dbResultSet.next()) {
                String ingredientnaam = dbResultSet.getString("ingredientnaam");
                Ingredient ingredient = ingredientDAO.findByString(ingredientnaam);

                Ingredient newIngredient = new Ingredient(ingredientnaam, 1, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);

                results.add(newIngredient);
            }
        } catch (SQLException sqle) {
            sqle.printStackTrace();
        }

        return results;
    }

    public List<Ingredient> findAll() {
        return selectIngredients("SELECT ingredientId, name, account, FK_ingredientID FROM ingredient");
    }

    public Ingredient findByString(String ingredientId) {
        return selectIngredients("SELECT ingredientnaam FROM ingredient WHERE ingredientnaam = " +ingredientId).get(0);
    }
}
```

IngredientService.java

```
package voedseldagboek.dagboek.domain;

import java.util.List;

import voedseldagboek.dagboek.persistence.*;

public class IngredientService {
    private IngredientDAO ingredientDAO = new IngredientDAO();

    public List<Ingredient> getAllIngredients() {
        return ingredientDAO.findAll();
    }
}
```

ServiceProvider.java

```
package voedseldagboek.dagboek.domain;

public class ServiceProvider {
    private static IngredientService ingredientService = new IngredientService();

    public static IngredientService getIngredientService() {
        return ingredientService;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you already made sure that your rest configuration is correct- that the call is hitting the method getIngredients?

Comment: @jay How would I go about checking this?